# What did Thomas Merton mean by cartesian when it comes to modern christianity?

Tags: catholicism, reformed-theology

Wikipedia article on [Thomas Merton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Merton) states:

> He believed that for the most part, Christianity had forsaken its
>   mystical tradition in favor of **Cartesian** emphasis on "the reification
>   of concepts, idolization of the reflexive consciousness, flight from
>   being into verbalism, mathematics, and rationalization.

What did he mean by **Cartesian**? Why did he use this word?

Comment: What did you find, yourself, when you looked up 'Cartesian' ?

Comment: I wonder if Thomas Merton truly understood what he meant when he mentioned the [Cartesianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesianism) about Christianity?

Comment: @Nigel J ["that the mind and body are distinct and separable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism#Substance_or_Cartesian_dualism)

Comment: @SijuGeorge Human mind and human body are neither distinct nor separable. Save in death, which will be overcome by resurrection.

Comment: @NigelJ Isn't the mind immaterial & body material? So why are they not distinct? And why are they not separable? How does one account for [Out-of-body experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-body_experience) if they are not separable?

Comment: @SijuGeorge Well, if Paul the apostle was unable to be clear on such an event, then neither am I. II Corinthians 12:3.

Answer (score 2):

In a very vague sense in many 19th and 20th century Christian writings when someone talks about "Cartesian" they mean they just mean whatever can be boiled down to the maxim:

> I think therefore I am

And like evolution, people get the impression that reading that line gives them all they need to know about *Principia philosophiae* the same way "Survival of the Fittest" gives them all they need to know about *Origin of Species*.  And because of this:

> It has the fatal quality of leaving on many minds the impression that they do understand it and everything else; just as many of them live under a sort of illusion that they have read the Origin of Species.
>
> G.K. Chesterton - The Everlasting Man

Maybe Thomas Merton was writing about something deeper. He was a popular author writing philosophy for the masses, and this, at least probably lends itself to the idea that describing something or someone as Cartesian means branding them a Materialist Philosophy; one that would be banned in happier times (i.e. the Middle Ages).

Comment: What about Cartesian dualism: dividing reality into "thinking things" (_res cogitans_) and "extended things" (_res extensa_)?

Comment: (cf. [De Koninck on the dogma of the Assumption](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xjas5aIXm1gl7YDyNCQ9QbnCOaVfppp6Q7Uq5cJAqzo/edit), which Pius XII defined in [_Munificentissimus Deus_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/apost_constitutions/documents/hf_p-xii_apc_19501101_munificentissimus-deus.html), which stresses, against Cartesian dualism, the unity of the human body and soul, since it proclaims that the Blessed Mother was assumed body _and_ soul into heaven)